# Issue in the Facebook auth dialog

Tags: facebook

I am trying to provide login using facebook option to my website users. So, I created one Facebook app .But the auth dialog box is showing only once for a user.That is for the first login the auth dialog box will show .For the next logins the auth dialog box is not showing.
I want to show the auth dialog box in each login for each users.

Comment: It might be a good idea to show your code aswell

Comment: And a little more explanation on _why_ you want to show it on each login please.

Comment: is it possible to show on each login?

Comment: thanks to everyone for the 'help'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this explains it?

> Logging off your App and Logging in With Another Account
>
> If you log on to your app with Facebook, and then log out and try to
>   log in again with a different Facebook account (using the same
>   browser), you will be immediatly logged in to the previous Facebook
>   acount you used.  In order to use another account, you need to
>   navigate to Facebook and log out at Facebook. The same rule applies to
>   any other 3rd party authentication provider. Alternatively, you can
>   log in with another account by using a different browser.

Taken from http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on